# What can Hollande do to prevent a Marine Le Pen victory?

Tags: voting, france

French President François Hollande said his "ultimate duty" is to [prevent a Marine Le Pen victory](http://www.businessinsider.com/r-outgoing-french-president-hollande-says-ultimate-duty-is-to-prevent-le-pen-victory-2017-3):

> "My ultimate duty is to make sure that France is not won over by such a program, and that France does not bear such a heavy responsibility," said Hollande of the risk of a Le Pen victory in the election.

Since people can vote for whoever they want, what can he do to prevent her victory?

Comment: With the credibility he has, I don't think he can do anything to prevent or aid a candidate's victory. The less he says, the better.

Answer (score 3):

He can **campaign for people to vote for other candidates**.

He can **personally vote for a different candidate**.

As clarified by [David Grinbergs comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/5407/david-grinberg), he **cannot** use his position as a President, or resources allocated to his office, to campaign for or against any particular candidate.

Comment: Worth adding what he **cannot** do, specifically he **cannot** use the official capacity and resources of his office to dissuade voters.

Comment: One cannpt vote for a different candidate and call "His single vote" as " *his **ultimate duty**  to make **sure** that  Marine Le Pen dont win* "

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - arguably, his very statement as quoted by the question is already running afoul of that prohibition. He's using the bully pulpit.  (this is similar to SE, where "there's a diamond on anything a moderator says, even if they aren't speaking as a moderator" concept)